# PHP turn array into foreach

Tags: php

I am trying to take the code below and turn it into a foreach loop instead of an array to populate some code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $first  = strtotime(date('01-m-Y'));
    $months = array();

    for ($i = 6; $i >= 1; $i--) {
       array_push($months, date('M', strtotime("-$i month", $first)));
    }

    print_r($months);
```

It is returning the results as

```
Array (
[0] => Jul
[1] => Aug
[2] => Sep
[3] => Oct
[4] => Nov
[5] => Dec
)
```

I am trying to format code so it looks like

```
{ y: 'Jul', a: 0},
{ y: 'Aug', a: 100},
{ y: 'Sep', a: 100},
{ y: 'Oct', a: 100},
{ y: 'Nov', a: 100},
{ y: 'Dec', a: 100}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You want a **JSON** string?

Comment: I am trying to use php to build a loop for my data from MYSQL to populate in Morris charts.

Comment: For foreach, you need array.

Comment: Take a look - https://eval.in/501474

Comment: I'd add the two flags that disable escaping of slashes and non-ASCII characters, they aren't necessary to produce JSON. Also make sure that you check the output of an empty `array`, for which the JSON representation is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it in the format you need, simply change your loop to this:

```
for ($i = 6; $i >= 1; $i--) {
   array_push($months, array('y' => date('M', strtotime("-$i month", $first)), 'a' => 0));
}

echo json_encode($months);
```

<sup>*You'll need to replace the `0` with however you get the number(`0/100/100/100/etc`)*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're trying to do?

However I have no idea what does the index "a" does. so just put 100 in it.

```
    for ($i = 6; $i >= 1; $i--) {
       array_push($months, array('y' => date('M', strtotime("-$i month", $first)), 'a' => 100));
    }

    echo json_encode($months); //if you want json
    print_r($months);
```